# Value Counting by Day for a Line Chart

Tags: graph, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a table with two columns. One column is a Date Time column that shows the date and time that an item was moved. The other column is the Item Number of the item moved. There are multiple rows per day (each containing only one item number - as items are moved one at a time), and over 500 days. The catch is, there are gaps between the dates. So sometimes the dates jump anywhere from two days forward to a month forward, Here is a sample table:

```
|       Date Time        | Item Number |
| ---------------------- | ----------- |
|05/25/2020 10:38:07 A.M |      SGH123 |
|05/25/2020 11:32:42 A.M |      APJ432 |
|05/26/2020 11:17:21 P.M |      SGH123 |
|05/26/2020 03:12:01 P.M |      SGH123 |
|05/29/2020 09:22:49 A.M |      JRG872 |
|07/21/2020 12:26:25 P.M.|      APJ432 |
```

I need to be able to do two things:

1: Create a line graph that shows the trend in total items moved per day a long period of time.

2: Allow functionality within the line graph to select a specific Item Number and see that Item Number's own individual trend (total per day) over a long period of time. (Can only show days that the item was moved)

I'm pretty stumped on how to achieve both of these. It has to be a line graph so that's where I'm stuck. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Choose a time resolution.  Parhaps you want to show the items moved per day, averaged over a month.  Thus your line graph will have 12 * 500 / 365 points.
2. Write code to do the averaging, either for all items or for a selected item, awhich outputs the points to line plotted.
3. Pass the points to your plotting routine

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by time resolution? How can I go about setting that? And what do you mean by averaging? Apologies, as I am very new to Power BI and can't find many answers elsewhere.

Comment: You choose the time resolution, then write code to implememt your choice.  You need to process your data to calculate the average number of moves per day ove the time period you coose.  Then pass the data points ( there will be 16 if you choose a month ) to your plotting application.

Comment: I'm looking to connect the days together and display the exact amount of moves for each day - not the averages. I don't have data for every day, there are gaps in the dates.

Comment: Well if you want a time resolution of one day, then your line plot will go to zero when there is a gap, and jump about like crazy for the other days.  Such a plot will not be very helpful for any purpose, because it will be so noisy.  Averaging out your data over a longer time step will remove a lot of noise and make any trends present visible.

Comment: Okay that clears things up for me - thank you! One last question - what functions in the code would I use to average and output the points to a line?

Comment: Depends on what code you are using to write your application.  My own expertise is in C++ running on a windows desktop.